# Statistical test to check if sampling was not uniform

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

Given a set of real numbers $X$ and a subset $Y \subset X$, I would like to demonstrate that $Y$ is not a result of a uniform sampling from $X$.

One solution that I thought recall [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140616/can-i-use-kolmogorov-smirnov-test-to-check-if-my-data-are-uniformly-distributed), that is:

1. Perform a uniform random sampling from $X$ to produce a subset $X_{unif} \subset X$ such that $|X_{unif}| = |Y|$.
2. Perform a Kolgomorov-Smirnov test on $X_{unif}$ and $Y$ to assess that they come from two different distributions.

By the way I think that since I have the original set $X$ is somewhat useless/wrong to perform an additional random sampling.

Do anyone know something that could solve this problem?

Comment: in my opinion probability to sample a subset $Y_0$ is equal to probability of sampling any other set $Y_i$. In general you can not prove that this particular subset $Y$ was selected non-randomly - unless you have a prior knowledge of what type of bias was used during subsampling. If you have such knowledge - construct test statistic based on this knowledge, take 1000 subsamples of size |Y| and check how many test statistics from these 1000 subsamples exceed (or equal) to yours. This will be your p-value.

Comment: I am not sure to have understood, you are proposing to use the solution I show in the question?

Comment: If you change "produce a subset" to "produce subsets" - I would say yes, and Kolmogorov-Smirnov test looks like terribly bad choice if you want to use p-values from it - but even if you use just W I doubt if it is a good choice of statistic especially if |Y| is small and |X| is quite complex.

Comment: Why not just perform a K-S test to compare $Y$ directly to the uniform distribution on $X$?  There's no need to construct a sample from $X$ in order to analyze your data!

Comment: @whuber but what do you mean by "uniform distribution on X"? Switch from X to indices 1...|X| and compare this to $i_1,...,i_{|Y|}$ with KS test? 0.o

Comment: @whuber I am not sure that performing KS test between $X$ and $Y$ actually answer to my needs, because I want to know if $X$ is not a random sample of $Y$ .

KS test check if the two samples are coming from the same distribution, but since $X$ is a subset of $Y$, I am not sure if KS between $X$ and $Y$ could be biased somehow.

Comment: obviously you don't need to perform stat test if Y comes from X if Y is actually a subsample of X - probability of this event is actually 1. You need to somehow switch to uniform distributions - but only whuber knows the dark secrets of this magic...

Comment: Balrog, the K-S test comes in both one-sample and two-sample forms.   BTW, there are plenty of tests you can apply: this is basically the question of how to test a random number generator; there exists a large literature and an enormous number of tests.  See, e.g., Knuth's *Art of Computer Programming.* @German By definition, the uniform distribution assigns equal probabilities to all elements.  There's no ambiguity about that.

Comment: @whuber I guess sampling here is without repetition. And size of |Y| is much smaller than |X| so even if we "return" values after each sampling step probability that the same element will be chosen twice is rather small. But if I say smth not really smart - just ignore it...

Comment: thanks a lot for the reference, what do you think about @Edgar answer?

Comment: I understood the answer and I subscribe to the point @whuber said. You don't need to re-sample anything. Just switch to indices of elements of |Y| and perform KS test on uniform distribution 1...|X|/

Comment: @German I would just like to remark that the subtleties you were alluding to in earlier comments derive from the fact that under the null, every subset (of a given size) of $X$ has equal chances of being sampled. Thus, there's absolutely no way to distinguish this $Y$ from any other subset  $Y^\prime.$ One makes progress by specifying an *alternative* to the null hypothesis: that is, exactly how could uniform sampling be violated? Might it consist, for instance, of unusually large or small gaps between the values of $Y$?  Until the OP tells us this, it will be hard to justify any answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would combine your idea of the KS-test and the [answer below your question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/402226/statistical-test-to-check-if-sampling-was-not-uniform#comment752707_402226), if the size of the $X$ and/or $Y$ is small:

Sample (uniformly) $B$ times (e.g. $B=1000$) a subset $X_b$ of $X$ of size $|Y|$ and calculate the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic $D_b$ from $X_b$ and $X$. This gives you an empirical distribution of the values $D_b$.

Calculate $D^{\ast}$ as the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic from $Y$ and $X$ and assess how many of your $D_b$, $b=1,\ldots,B$ are larger than or equal to your $D^{\ast}$, this gives you the approximate $p$-value: $p=\#\lbrace D_b\geq D^{\ast} \rbrace/B$.

If $p$ is smaller than a pre-defined $\alpha$, you can reject the null hypothesis that $Y$ was sampled uniformly with error $\alpha$.

If $|X|$ and $|Y|$ are large, you can calculate the KS-statistic $D^{\ast}$ directly and use tabellarized values to assess significance.

Comment: $|X| \sim 3k$ and $|Y| \sim 6M$. Do you think that the two sizes allow to directly perform KS-test between $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: I guess it is the other way around, $|X|\approx6\cdot10^6$ and $|Y|\approx3\cdot10^3$? Yes, 3000 data points [should be enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Kolmogorov_distribution).

Comment: Yes sorry, it is as you say. Thanks for the clarifications.